# Is it possible to use partition as bootable media?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, partitioning, windows-7-upgrade

I use Windows 7 and I wanna upgrade to Windows 10. I don't wanna use microsoft's Media creation tool. I got lite Windows 10 ISO file. I wanna install it but I got no USB stick and my pc couldn't detect Drivedroid on bios. If we can install Windows 10 without USB drive and etc then it means we can install other iso files like this too. Now how can I do it?

Comment: Is your question about booting ISO or upgrading to Windows 10?  You don't need to put ISO on USB key or partition to upgrade.  Just [Extract an ISO File to the Windows Desktop](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/170795-iso-disk-image-file-extract-desktop.html) and click on `setup.exe`.

Comment: @lx07 that ``setup.exe`` files not opening. They all says that I need to launch it from USB or CD.

Answer (score 0):

An ISO isn't bootable directly, it first needs to be mounted.

However, you can upgrade WIn7 to Win10 directly from the running Win7 installation.
Download the Windows Media Creation tool, run it as if you were going to create a boot USB, but at the last step just select "Upgrade this PC now".

Comment: But I got Lite Windows 10 iso. I wanna install Lite iso, not original.

Comment: Ah, the "unnoficial" version.. You're on your own with that, sorry.